# Can I extract the contents of an iso file with Ant?

Tags: ant, extract, iso

Is there a way I can extract the contents of an ISO file using Apache Ant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just shell out to a [utility](http://www.peazip.org/) to extract the iso.

Comment: I ended up using 7zip and the command line "7z e my.iso". It's a shame a I needed to add a dependency on an extra tool though.

Answer (score 1):

There's an Ant library for *creating* ISO 9660 images [here](http://jiic.berlios.de/), but it doesn't seem to support extracting them.  Perhaps you could grab the source and have a go at making it extract as well as create.